# Tips to improve performance of Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I have a requirement where I need to set the height of each row of a table based on the corresponding row in another table.The table has around 500 rows.
I have written the below Javascript, but the performance is really bad around 8000 ms.
How can I make this faster, appreciate any tips .

```
 var start = new Date().getTime();


 var rows = document.getElementById("table1").rows;
 var dup_rows = document.getElementById("table2").rows;
 var num_rows = rows.length;
 var num_dup = dup_rows.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
var hg = rows[i].offsetHeight;
    rows[i].style.height = hg +'px';
dup_rows[i].style.height = hg +'px';
   }

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
alert('Execution time: ' + time);
```

Based on the Suggestion to edit the tables outside of DOM, I tried the below, but the outerHeight / offsetHeight returns 0 when the table is removed from DOM.

```
      clone_small = $('#table2').clone();
      clone_main_tab = $('#table1').clone();
 $("#table2").remove();
 $("#table1").remove();

 $(clone_main_tab).find("tr").each(function(i) {
 var hg = 0;
 hg = $(this).offsetHeight;  // If I hard code the height it works
  // alert(hg);
 $(this).height(hg);
 clone_small.find("tr").eq(i).height(hg);


 });
```

How can I set the height of these rows outside the DOM ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the element that you are modifying from the DOM, then re-insert them when you are done modifying them. This prevents the browser having to reflow the document with every change, only doing it once when you're all finished.

Comment: thanks for your response, However I could not get the syntax right, can you please help me with that I tried to use jquery to do that, but ended up with syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `dup_rows[i].style.height = rows[i].style.height` better?

Comment: I agree. Why get the height just to set it one line later?

Comment: I want both table's tr be of equal height

Comment: Yes but the performance is not good so I was trying to achieve the same results with better performance

Comment: I tried the below code but the height is returning 0. var dup_rows = document.getElementById("table2").rows; var rows = document.getElementById("table1").rows; var num_rows = rows.length; var $mem_tab2 = $("#table2"); var $mem_tab = $("#table1"); $("#table2").remove(); $("#table1").remove(); for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) { var hg = rows[i].offsetHeight; rows[i].style.height = hg +'px'; dup_rows[i].style.height = hg + 'px'; } $("#div2").append($mem_tab2); $("#div").append($mem_tab);

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to achieve some improvement in performance by using the below code

```
 $clone_table1 = $('#table1').clone();
 $clone_table2 = $('#table2').clone();

 $('#table2').remove();
 $trow2 = $('#table1').find('tr');
 $trow = $clone_table1.find('tr');
 $trow3 = $clone_table2.find('tr');

 $trow.each(function(i) {
 var hg = 0;
 hg = $trow2.eq(i).outerHeight();
 $(this).height(hg);
 $trow3.eq(i).height(hg);
 });


$parent2.append($clone_table2);
$('#table1').remove();
$parent1.append($clone_table1);
```